# Python tkinter Label set method with textvariable launched from another window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a weird issue with a textvariable reference in tkinter and I can't find a way to formulate a clean question so that I can find an answer instead of asking.

In the code below, if I call `PromptTradeAlloc(ref=4, sym="AAPL")` the labels (inside a LabelFrame) will set perfectly as instructed.

[image]

However, if I call the previous class from `PromptTradesLog()` select the line in the Listbox and then click 'Open Trade' the Labels set method does not seem to work.

[image]
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *

class PromptTradesLog:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.minsize(400, 250)
        self.root.title('Last 10 Trades')
        self.root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
        self.t = Listbox(self.root, width=50)

        Button(self.root, text="Delete", command=self.delete_command).grid(column=0, row=12, padx=(10, 2), sticky=N)
        Button(self.root, text="Open Trade", command=self.open_trade).grid(column=1, row=12, padx=(10, 2), sticky=N)
        Button(self.root, text="Commit", command=self.commit_command).grid(column=2, row=12, padx=(10, 2), sticky=N)
        self.t.insert(END, "THIS IS A TEST")
        self.t.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=15, rowspan=10, padx=10, pady=(0, 10))

        self.root.mainloop()


    def delete_command(self):
        pass

    def open_trade(self):
        """
        open a trade to make some modifications
        Calls PromptTradeAlloc which opens a new window with different features
        """
        PromptTradeAlloc(ref=4, sym="AAPL")

    def commit_command(self):
        pass


class PromptTradeAlloc:
    def __init__(self, ref, sym):
        super().__init__()
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.minsize(200, 100)
        self.root.title(f'Trade #{ref} for {sym}')
        self.root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
        self.t = Listbox(self.root, width=15,  height=15)
        self.ref = ref

        self.t.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=15, rowspan=50, padx=10, pady=(1, 10))

        self.t.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.populate)

        info = LabelFrame(self.root, text=sym)
        ff = Frame(self.root)

        # set the textvariable as StringVar
        # these are set in the self.reload_list() function
        self.total_amt = StringVar()
        self.total_qty = StringVar()
        Label(info, textvariable=self.total_amt, justify=LEFT).grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, padx=2)
        Label(info, textvariable=self.total_qty, justify=LEFT).grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, padx=2)

        Label(ff, text="Fond", width=10).grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.fond_lbl = StringVar()
        Label(ff,
              textvariable=self.fond_lbl,
              relief='solid',
              borderwidth=1,
              width=10).grid(row=3, column=0)

        Label(ff, text="Qty", width=10).grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.qty_entry = Entry(ff, width=10)
        self.qty_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

        Label(ff, text="New Fond", width=10).grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.fond_entry = Entry(ff, width=10)
        self.fond_entry.grid(row=3, column=2)

        Button(ff, text="Delete", command=self.delete_command).grid(row=4, column=0, pady=4)
        Button(ff, text="Update", command=self.update_command).grid(row=4, column=1, pady=4)
        Button(ff, text="Add", command=self.add_command).grid(row=4, column=2, pady=4)

        info.grid(row=1, column=18, rowspan=2, columnspan=3)
        ff.grid(row=3, column=18, columnspan=3)

        self.reload_list()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def populate(self, event):
        pass

    def spaces(self, symbol, lmt):
        l = len(symbol)
        return f"{symbol}{(lmt-l)*' '}"

    def reload_list(self):
        self.t.insert(END, "This is another test")

        self.t.config(font=('Courier', "11"))

        # this is where I set the textvariable strings
        self.total_amt.set("Total Amt:\nSET 1")
        self.total_qty.set(f"Total Qty:\nSET 2")

        self.root.update()

    def delete_command(self):
        pass

    def update_command(self):
        pass

    def add_command(self):
        pass

# PromptTradesLog()
# PromptTradeAlloc(ref=4, sym="AAPL")
```

Comment: The problem is because you are creating two instances of `Tk`. You need to have exactly  one.

Comment: `tkinter` should have only one main window - `Tk()` - and for others you should use `Toplevel()`. And only one `mainloop()`

Comment: Thank you both my issue is fixed and it works like a charm,  gonna apply that going forward

Comment: BTW: it seems you could resolve it also using `StringVar(self.root)` - but it is preferred to use `Toplevel()` to create second window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`tkinter` should have only one main window - `Tk()` - and for other windows you should use `Toplevel()`. And you should use only one `mainloop()`. And this resolves your problem.

---

**BTW:** It seems you could resolve it also using `StringVar(self.root)` without other changes but it is preferred to use `Toplevel()` to create second window.